# Two tables Inner Join to show data

Tags: c#, asp.net, join

I am currently working on a SQL query using `INNER JOIN` to retrieve specific columns from two tables, `Tbl_Registration` and `Tbl_Class`. In `Tbl_Registration`, there is a column called `Class_ID`, and in `Tbl_Class`, there is a column named `Class_Name`.

Despite my efforts, I am unable to fetch the desired `Class_Name`; instead, the query is returning the `Class_ID`. How can I modify my query to successfully retrieve the `Class_Name` using the INNER JOIN?

```
public ActionResult TestSchedule(int? selectedClassId)
{
    IQueryable<Tbl_Registration> registrations = dbContext.Tbl_Registration;

    if (selectedClassId.HasValue && selectedClassId.Value > 0)
    {
        registrations = registrations.Where(r => r.Class_ID == selectedClassId.Value);
    }

    registrations = dbContext.Tbl_Registration
                             .Where(r => r.Class_ID.HasValue)
                             .Join(dbContext.Tbl_Class,
                                   reg => reg.Class_ID.Value,
                                   cls => cls.Class_ID,
                                   (reg, cls) => new Tbl_Registration
                                                 {
                                                     NameOfApplicant = reg.NameOfApplicant,
                                                     Father_Name = reg.Father_Name,
                                                     Father_Email = reg.Father_Email,
                                                     Father_MobileNumber = reg.Father_MobileNumber,
                                                     DateOfBirth = reg.DateOfBirth,
                                                     Created_On = reg.Created_On,
                                                     Picture = reg.Picture,
                                                     B_Certificate = reg.B_Certificate,
                                                     Class_Name = cls.Class_Name
                                                 });

    ViewBag.ClassList = dbContext.Tbl_Class
                                 .Select(c => new SelectListItem  
                                                  { 
                                                      Value = c.Class_ID.ToString(), 
                                                      Text = c.Class_Name
                                                  })
                                 .ToList();

    return View(registrations.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning `registrations = dbContext.Tbl_Registration` after the if, you are basically resetting the query, you should be persisting reassign the existing variable:

```
registrations = registrations
    .Where(r => r.Class_ID.HasValue)
```

Or, you can write the entire thing as one query:

```
registrations = dbContext.Tbl_Registration
.Where(r => r.Class_ID.HasValue && (!selectedClassId.HasValue || r.Class_ID.Value == selectedClassId.Value))
.Join(dbContext.Tbl_Class,
    reg => reg.Class_ID.Value,
    cls => cls.Class_ID,
    (reg, cls) => new Tbl_Registration
    {
        reg.NameOfApplicant,
        reg.Father_Name,
        reg.Father_Email,
        reg.Father_MobileNumber,
        reg.DateOfBirth,
        reg.Created_On,
        reg.Picture,
        reg.B_Certificate,
        Class_Name = cls.Class_Name
    });
```

But I personally prefer your way though; easier to read.